# Why does Access VBA Project "Help File Name" contain random numbers?

Tags: vba, ms-access

**Using MS-Access 64-bit O365 Version 2103 (Build 13901.20336 Click-to-run)**

I noticed that the "Help File Name" contained some numbers recently. I thought this was odd because I've never used that field. I've never made a custom help file. The numbers change every time I look at my project details.

EXAMPLE:

[image]

So I tried clearing it out. Set it to blank because I don't need it. If I make it blank I can check it multiple times and see that it is blank. Then if I run a single line of VBA code a new random number appears in that field. Doesn't matter what kind of code I step in to, I get new numbers in there.

If I export my database to text files for version control I see these random numbers in my DB properties for the help file name.

What is going on here? Is this just Access corruption? Does a number ever make sense here? Shouldn't it be a string containing a filename?

Comment: What version of Access? Export project to what? How do you do export?

Comment: Then where does that form come from?

Comment: Right click on your project in the VBE and select properties. Top item on the left hand bar.This is how you name your project. Have you never named a VBA project?

Comment: Sorry, cannot replicate issue. Does this happen for any db? So if corruption is cause, try decompiling then recompiling (Google the topic) and/or import objects to new file. There is still no code to analyze. Been a while since I bothered naming a db but yes apparently I have used it.

Comment: I have done many decompile\recompile operations. Compact and repair. It still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At long last I learned that the reason is that I use [RubberDuck VBA](https://rubberduckvba.com/)

The explanation can be found in [Issue#3355](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/3355) of their GitHub:

> According to the wiki, RD will store ProjectID in the project help file.

If we look at the [Wiki](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/The-Parsing-Process) it is only mentioned briefly:

> Projects are bit more tricky since they are usually treated as equal
> if their projectIds are the same; we save these in the project help
> file.

Comment: Also see [issue 5741](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/5741) to track the progress of retiring this legacy functionality from RubberDuck.